# Convert different length list in pandas dataframe to row in one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table like this in pandas, the date is always Friday but it could be not continuous due to holidays or other reasons, and in Target, it is a list that contains the performance of next week, the length of the list in the last row could be <5 because today is Wednesday, so for this week I only have Monday and Tuesday data:

```
| Date         | Performance          |
| 2022/01/27   | [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3]|
| 2022/02/10   | [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3]|
| 2022/02/17   | [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3]|
| 2022/02/24   | [0.1,0.1]            |
```

I want to convert this table to a date/performance 2d table with the date of the actual performance day and the performance of each day:

```
| Date         | Performance |
| 2022/01/30   |0.1 |
| 2022/01/31   |0.1 |
| 2022/02/01   |0.2 |
| 2022/02/02   |0.1 |
| 2022/02/03   |0.3 |
| 2022/02/13   |0.1 |
| 2022/02/14   |0.1 |
| 2022/02/15   |0.2 |
| ...          |... |
| 2022/02/27   |0.1 |
| 2022/02/28   |0.1 |
```

How can I do this in python?

I tried to use sum for the list to connect all lists to a 1d array, but it is problem to attach it to the date column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand about your description of the DataFrame, its columns represent the following:

- `date`: contains dates which are all consecutive **Fridays**.
- `performance`: contains lists of performances corresponding to consecutive days in the next week (from Monday up to at most Friday), i.e. `3` days after the value in `date`.

And the problem is how to form a DataFrame that has each performance and its corresponding date on a separate row.

---

### Input data

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'date': ['2022/01/27', '2022/02/10', '2022/02/17', '2022/02/24'],
    'performance': [
        [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3],
        [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3],
        [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3],
        [0.1,0.1]
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

```
         date                performance
0  2022/01/27  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]
1  2022/02/10  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]
2  2022/02/17  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]
3  2022/02/24                 [0.1, 0.1]
```

---

### Simple solution

[Jamiu S. provided a much more compact solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75599016/21283023) than my original one. So I've include it here first, with the addition of [`pd.DateOffset()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) to fully answer the question.

```py
df = df.explode('performance')

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.DateOffset(days=3) + pd.to_timedelta(
             df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='D') 

df = df.reset_index(drop=True) 
print(df)
```

Output:

```
         date performance
0  2022-01-30         0.1
1  2022-01-31         0.1
2  2022-02-01         0.2
3  2022-02-02         0.1
4  2022-02-03         0.3
5  2022-02-13         0.1
6  2022-02-14         0.1
7  2022-02-15         0.2
8  2022-02-16         0.1
9  2022-02-17         0.3
10 2022-02-20         0.1
11 2022-02-21         0.1
12 2022-02-22         0.2
13 2022-02-23         0.1
14 2022-02-24         0.3
15 2022-02-27         0.1
16 2022-02-28         0.1
```

---

### Original solution

Consider the following steps:

##### Step 1: Converting dates to `datetime`

If not done so already, ensure the `date` values are represented as `datetime` objects rather than strings. The [`pd.to_datetime()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.to_datetime.html) method can be used to accomplish this.

```py
# Convert the date column to a datetime object, so it can be manipulated later.
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

print(df)
```

```
        date                performance
0 2022-01-27  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]
1 2022-02-10  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]
2 2022-02-17  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]
3 2022-02-24                 [0.1, 0.1]
```

Output of `df.info()`:

```
RangeIndex: 4 entries, 0 to 3
Data columns (total 2 columns):
 #   Column       Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------       --------------  -----         
 0   date         4 non-null      datetime64[ns]
 1   performance  4 non-null      object        
dtypes: datetime64[ns](1), object(1)
memory usage: 192.0+ bytes
```

---

##### Step 2: Adding the date of next week

Add a new column `'start_of_week'`, representing the Monday of the next week (`3` days after Friday).

To calculate these dates, [`pd.DateOffset()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) can be used, to advance the original dates by certain number of days.

```py
# Create a column representing the start of the next week (Monday) - 3 days after the current date (Friday)
df['start_of_week'] = df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=3)

print(df)
```

```
        date                performance start_of_week
0 2022-01-27  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]    2022-01-30
1 2022-02-10  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]    2022-02-13
2 2022-02-17  [0.1, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.3]    2022-02-20
3 2022-02-24                 [0.1, 0.1]    2022-02-27
```

---

##### Step 3: Creating a performance table generator

Create a function that can be applied to each row, to form a two-dimensional "performance table" out of it.

The `pd.date_range()` function can be used to form a sequence of consecutive `dates` corresponding to each performance value.

```py
# Generates a sub-DataFrame out of a row containing a week-date and performances.
def create_performance_table(r):
    
    # Extract the performance dates.
    perfs = r['performance']
    
    # Construct the range of dates corresponding to each of these performances
    dates = pd.date_range(r['start_of_week'], periods = len(perfs))

    # Create a DataFrame out of these values and return it.
    return pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "performance": perfs})
```

---

##### Step 4: Creating the sub-tables and combining them

Use the newly defined `create_performance_table()` function to construct the DataFrame representing the whole performance table.

- The [`.apply()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) method applies the function to each row of the DataFrame, and combines them together.
- Since the resulting sub-tables will be represented as a single `Series` object, they need to be joined together to form a single `DataFrame`. The [`.concat()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) method can do just that (but the `Series` must first be converted to a list).

```py
# Apply the performance table generator to every row, storing the results as a Series of sub-DataFrames.
tables = df[['performance', 'start_of_week']].apply(create_performance_table, axis=1)

# Concatenate each of these sub-DatFrames to form the final performance table
out_df = pd.concat(tables.tolist(), ignore_index=True)

print(out_df)
```

Final output:

```
         date  performance
0  2022-01-30          0.1
1  2022-01-31          0.1
2  2022-02-01          0.2
3  2022-02-02          0.1
4  2022-02-03          0.3
5  2022-02-13          0.1
6  2022-02-14          0.1
7  2022-02-15          0.2
8  2022-02-16          0.1
9  2022-02-17          0.3
10 2022-02-20          0.1
11 2022-02-21          0.1
12 2022-02-22          0.2
13 2022-02-23          0.1
14 2022-02-24          0.3
15 2022-02-27          0.1
16 2022-02-28          0.1
```

---

### Full code

```py
import pandas as pd

# --- Input data

data = {
    'date': ['2022/01/27', '2022/02/10', '2022/02/17', '2022/02/24'],
    'performance': [
        [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3],
        [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3],
        [0.1,0.1,0.2,0.1,0.3],
        [0.1,0.1]
    ]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)


# --- Convert dates to datetime

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])


# --- Add the date of next week

df['start_of_week'] = df['date'] + pd.DateOffset(days=3)


# --- Performance table generator

def create_performance_table(r):
    
    perfs = r['performance']
    
    dates = pd.date_range(r['start_of_week'], periods = len(perfs))

    return pd.DataFrame({"date": dates, "performance": perfs})


# --- Create the sub-tables and combine them

tables = df[['performance', 'start_of_week']].apply(create_performance_table, axis=1)

# The final output
out_df = pd.concat(tables.tolist(), ignore_index=True)
```

Comment: Thank you.  Very clear for understanding.  I think it is more helpful to combine your answer with Jamiu S.'s answer.

Comment: @Yiwei Great idea, since his solution is much more compact than mine.

I've added it to my answer, and adapted it to better answer your original question (simply add `pd.DateOffset(days=3)`).

Answer (score 4):

Here is an approach using [`df.explode()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) and [`df.groupby().cumcount()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html)

```py
df = df.explode('Performance')
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date']) + pd.to_timedelta(
             df.groupby(level=0).cumcount(), unit='D')

df = df.reset_index(drop=True) 
print(df)
```

---

```
         Date Performance
0  2022-01-27         0.1
1  2022-01-28         0.1
2  2022-01-29         0.2
3  2022-01-30         0.1
4  2022-01-31         0.3
5  2022-02-10         0.1
6  2022-02-11         0.1
7  2022-02-12         0.2
8  2022-02-13         0.1
9  2022-02-14         0.3
10 2022-02-17         0.1
11 2022-02-18         0.1
12 2022-02-19         0.2
13 2022-02-20         0.1
14 2022-02-21         0.3
15 2022-02-24         0.1
16 2022-02-25         0.1
```

Comment: Hi Jamiu,  Thank you for your answer.  For Date column, How can I convert Friday to Monday and then I can try your approach.

Comment: You just have to add 3 days using `pd.DateOffset ` before adding `pd.to_timedelta` method. And I could see that **user21283023** has added that to his answer.